# Java check if MouseReleased position is between two points

Tags: java, mouseevent, panel, point, mouselistener

I have a game where you click on a panel, and yes the panel is getting the action command (tested by printing words when i click the panel). How can you check if `Point MosPos = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();` if between two points.

```
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource().equals(panel)) {
        Point MosPos = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        if (MosPos >= new Point(0, 0) && MosPos <= new Point(100, 100)) {
            System.out.println("working.");
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Instance names should always start with a lowercase letter. MosPos should be mosPos. This is to avoid confusion just in case MosPos is another class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
int x = event.getX();
int y = event.getY();
```

if you want a point:

```
Point p = event.getPoint();
```

then to compare:

```
int start = 0;
int end = 100;

if(x >= start && x <= end &&
    y >= start && y <= end)
    System.out.println("working");
```